Javascript not work properly in Loop Grid widget(Elementor Pro)
I have a loop item template, where among other things, there is a button widget (with no click on it, used just for shape and easy to use) that fetches a custom field value from the post. This value is a number between 0-100. The button is accompanied by a script that changes the color of the button based on the value in it.
Now here's the problem:
When using this template for the loop grid widget, the script works only for the first post in the list. All other post have standard color buttons that does not depend on the value in it. All other things work fine. My only problem is to let this javascript work for every element in the loop grid widget. I tried to put the script not in the loop item template but in page where the the loop grid widget will be used, but it doesn't work either.
The button has the ID set to 'myButton', and I thought that's where the problem lies, maybe in subsequent elements of the loop grid, the buttons lose that id?
Edit:
I will add some extra info. I can't give more HTML because i'm using mostly elementor to do so. The only code I wrote was the script. But i can give you some example and a step-by-step process that I followed.
Let's say I have 3 posts, which we will call postA, postB, postC.
Each post has a custom field( created via the ACF plugin) which can be different or the same as other posts. This custom field we will call it 'Number' and it is always a value between 0 and 100(integer). postA has the 'Number' set to 12, postB to 99, postC to 72.
My intent is to create, using Elementor, a 'loop item' that shows post name. Under that, the custom field 'Number' inside a circle whose color changes based on the value of 'Number' itself.
Now, since I don't know how to take the value of 'Number' through a code written directly by me, and instead of creating an element with text in the middle in html, modifying it in the form of a circle and with specific color in CSS, I decided to use Elementor's 'Button' widget, which allows me easily to take the value of 'Number' from the current post in which it is located, and also is easy to modify for creating the circle with value inside that I am trying to achieve(of course I removed the possibility to 'click' on the button and any animation, making it a simple static circle).
With that done, what was left for me to do was to create the script that would dynamically change the color of the button. The code I wrote, inserted via Elementor's 'HTML' widget, works fine, but only for the first button it finds, since I'm using the ID that should be unique.
The final intent is in fact to insert on a page, via Elementor's 'Loop Grid' widget,(where the 'Loop Item' created just now is to be selected), a list of all the posts, with their name and their custom field 'number'.
It should therefore come out something like:

The button is NOT an actual button(no click option, no link, nothing happen if clicked), i simply use the widget 'button' of elementor to easly put the circle, edit it and easly get the 'Number' value inside it.
Clearly, the script I wrote only works with the first element, in fact postA has the button where it is inserted, colored red. The other two following, however, have their button where the custom field ‘Number’ is inserted in a generic color (the one set by default in the widget itself) and not like in the image.


    function getColor(value) {
        const colors = {
            0: '#F50000', 1: '#F50000', 2: '#F50000', 3: '#F50000', 4: '#F50000', 5: '#F50000', 6: '#F50000', 7: '#F50000', 8: '#F50000', 9: '#F50000',
            10: '#F50000', 11: '#F50000', 12: '#F50000', 13: '#F50000', 14: '#F50000', 15: '#F50000', 16: '#F50000', 17: '#F50000', 18: '#F50000', 19: '#F50000',
            20: '#F50000', 21: '#F50000', 22: '#F50000', 23: '#F50000', 24: '#F50000', 25: '#F50000', 26: '#F50000', 27: '#F50000', 28: '#F50000', 29: '#F50000',
            30: '#F50000', 31: '#F50000', 32: '#F50000', 33: '#F50000', 34: '#F50000', 35: '#F50000', 36: '#F50000', 37: '#F50000', 38: '#F50000', 39: '#F50000',
            40: '#F50000', 41: '#F50000', 42: '#F00000', 43: '#EB0000', 44: '#E60000', 45: '#E10000', 46: '#DC0000', 47: '#D70000', 48: '#D20000', 49: '#CD0000',
            50: '#C80000', 51: '#C80A00', 52: '#C81400', 53: '#C81E00', 54: '#C82800', 55: '#C83200', 56: '#C83C00', 57: '#C84600', 58: '#C85000', 59: '#C85A00',
            60: '#C86400', 61: '#C86E00', 62: '#C87800', 63: '#C88200', 64: '#C88C00', 65: '#C89600', 66: '#C8A000', 67: '#C8AA00', 68: '#C8B400', 69: '#C8BE00',
            70: '#C8C800', 71: '#BEC800', 72: '#B4C800', 73: '#AAC800', 74: '#A0C800', 75: '#96C800', 76: '#8CC800', 77: '#82C800', 78: '#78C800', 79: '#6EC800',
            80: '#64C800', 81: '#5AC800', 82: '#50C800', 83: '#46C800', 84: '#3CC800', 85: '#32C800', 86: '#28C800', 87: '#1EC800', 88: '#14C800', 89: '#0AC800',
            90: '#00C800', 91: '#00CD00', 92: '#00D200', 93: '#00D700', 94: '#00DC00', 95: '#00E100', 96: '#00E600', 97: '#00EB00', 98: '#00F000', 99: '#00F500',
            100: '#00FA00'
        };
        return colors[value];
    }

    function updateCircle() {
        const button = document.getElementById('myButton');
        const value = parseInt(button.innerText, 10);
        const primaryColor = '#605BE5'; // primary color fixed
        const secondaryColor = getColor(value);
        button.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(to bottom, ${primaryColor}, ${secondaryColor} 80%)`;
    }

    // Constantly update color
    setInterval(updateCircle, 10);
<button id="myButton">1</button>



This is the html code for one button (in the example this is the first, 12 red)
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-29412fc elementor-align-left elementor-widget elementor-widget-button" data-id="29412fc" data-element_type="widget" data-settings="{&quot;motion_fx_motion_fx_scrolling&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;motion_fx_devices&quot;:[&quot;desktop&quot;,&quot;tablet&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;]}" data-widget_type="button.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
        <a class="elementor-button elementor-size-md" role="button">
                    <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                                <span class="elementor-button-text">12</span>
                </span>
                </a>
    </div>
            </div>
            </div>


I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS and note that IDs need to be unique

I suggest you also move const colors... outside the function. Why create this each time?

That's probably the problem, the ID must be unique. But I can't find another way to get the script to work in relation to the button other than using the ID. How else can I refer to the 'button' objects by making them all the same, as having the same ID, and then applying the same script to all of them?

Please post more HTML. What is the point of looping using setInterval? Is the idea to give every button a different colour? Then you can do that once. It is not clear what you want. You can give the buttons a class or just look at the textContent if that is unique

Go into your dev tools and copy the HTML from the rendered page and add it to the question. Also, this doesn't answer, but if you use buttons, your site won't be accessible to users that use a keyboard, as the keyboard will focus on buttons that don't do anything.

So when the page updates with more posts, you get more buttons?
Here is a script that will add a button to every elemento-element based on the value in elementor-button-text


const updateCircle = () => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-element'))
    .forEach(element => {
      if (element.querySelector('.articleButton')) return; // already has a button
      const val = element.querySelector('.elementor-button-text').textContent.trim();
      element.innerHTML += `<button class="articleButton">${val}</button>`
    })

  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.articleButton');
  buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
    const value = parseInt(button.textContent, 10);
    const primaryColor = '#605BE5'; // primary color fixed
    const secondaryColor = colors[value]; // find a better calculation depending on number of posts
    button.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(to bottom, ${primaryColor}, ${secondaryColor} 80%)`;
  });
};

// Constantly update color
setInterval(updateCircle, 1000);

/* Testing
const section = document.querySelector('section');
const alphabet = Array.from({
  length: 26
}, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(65 + i));

const rndLetter = (array) => {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  return array.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
}
const len = Object.keys(colors).length;
let tId = setInterval(() => {
  const letter = rndLetter(alphabet);
  if (alphabet.length === 0) {
    clearInterval(tId);
    return;
  }
  section.innerHTML += `<article id="post-${letter}" class="stratum-advanced-posts__post">
    <div class="stratum-advanced-posts__post-wrapper">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/50x80?text=POST ${letter} image" />
      <div class="stratum-advanced-posts__post-thumbnail">
        ${Math.floor(Math.random() * len)}</div>
    </div>
  </article>`
}, 1000)

*/
.articleButton {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 35px;
}

.elementor-element {
  display: flex;
}
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-29412fc elementor-align-left elementor-widget elementor-widget-button" data-id="29412fc" data-element_type="widget" data-settings="{&quot;motion_fx_motion_fx_scrolling&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;motion_fx_devices&quot;:[&quot;desktop&quot;,&quot;tablet&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;]}"
  data-widget_type="button.default">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
      <a class="elementor-button elementor-size-md" role="button">
        <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
          <span class="elementor-button-text">12</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  const colors = {
    0: '#F50000',
    1: '#F50000',
    2: '#F50000',
    3: '#F50000',
    4: '#F50000',
    5: '#F50000',
    6: '#F50000',
    7: '#F50000',
    8: '#F50000',
    9: '#F50000',
    10: '#F50000',
    11: '#F50000',
    12: '#F50000',
    13: '#F50000',
    14: '#F50000',
    15: '#F50000',
    16: '#F50000',
    17: '#F50000',
    18: '#F50000',
    19: '#F50000',
    20: '#F50000',
    21: '#F50000',
    22: '#F50000',
    23: '#F50000',
    24: '#F50000',
    25: '#F50000',
    26: '#F50000',
    27: '#F50000',
    28: '#F50000',
    29: '#F50000',
    30: '#F50000',
    31: '#F50000',
    32: '#F50000',
    33: '#F50000',
    34: '#F50000',
    35: '#F50000',
    36: '#F50000',
    37: '#F50000',
    38: '#F50000',
    39: '#F50000',
    40: '#F50000',
    41: '#F50000',
    42: '#F00000',
    43: '#EB0000',
    44: '#E60000',
    45: '#E10000',
    46: '#DC0000',
    47: '#D70000',
    48: '#D20000',
    49: '#CD0000',
    50: '#C80000',
    51: '#C80A00',
    52: '#C81400',
    53: '#C81E00',
    54: '#C82800',
    55: '#C83200',
    56: '#C83C00',
    57: '#C84600',
    58: '#C85000',
    59: '#C85A00',
    60: '#C86400',
    61: '#C86E00',
    62: '#C87800',
    63: '#C88200',
    64: '#C88C00',
    65: '#C89600',
    66: '#C8A000',
    67: '#C8AA00',
    68: '#C8B400',
    69: '#C8BE00',
    70: '#C8C800',
    71: '#BEC800',
    72: '#B4C800',
    73: '#AAC800',
    74: '#A0C800',
    75: '#96C800',
    76: '#8CC800',
    77: '#82C800',
    78: '#78C800',
    79: '#6EC800',
    80: '#64C800',
    81: '#5AC800',
    82: '#50C800',
    83: '#46C800',
    84: '#3CC800',
    85: '#32C800',
    86: '#28C800',
    87: '#1EC800',
    88: '#14C800',
    89: '#0AC800',
    90: '#00C800',
    91: '#00CD00',
    92: '#00D200',
    93: '#00D700',
    94: '#00DC00',
    95: '#00E100',
    96: '#00E600',
    97: '#00EB00',
    98: '#00F000',
    99: '#00F500',
    100: '#00FA00'
  };
</script>




No this is't what i mean, thanks for the try tough. I edited the question, may it help to undertand the situation.

Ok see update....

I have added a test for you

still, this is not what i mean, i did an image to better understand the final result

Ok, look again.....

i think this can be the right way, but what do you mean: "Change the article.querySelector('.stratum-advanced-posts__post-thumbnail to whatever selector works for you"? Should I insert here the code for get the custom field of the post? If yes, i truly do not know how to do it

What was your plan to do it? If you do not show the actual HTML, and you do not know how to do it yourself, how can we ever be able to help? I even went to a site that USE Elementor to try to find some kind of HTML I could work from. I am pretty sure it had some other classes than you have, hence my comment.
You need to right-click the number you want and then click inspect. Then you can see the HTML and the classes that might lead you to a selector that you can use

added html code of the widget

Ok, Have a look at my update
